# Not able to get ajax response when triggering cron job using post method

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, cron

I have written my HTML page where I am entering hours and minutes and passing that data to a CRON expression using a POST request.

The CRON expression executes when ever the time matches with the inputs, so until that AJAX can't wait for so long, so I am getting an error and I am not able to send a response back to the AJAX call.

```js
//outobj -> here object will have hour and minute
outobj { sh_hour : 1 , sh_minutes : 20 }
```

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: outobj,
  url: '/schedulerdata',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  },
});

app.post("/schedulerdata", function(req, res) {
  cron.schedule('0 ' + sh_minutes + ' ' + sh_hour + ' * * *', function() {
    console.log('\n running cron expression based on inputs \n');
  })
```

Comment: how long is your cron process running before logging the message ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Is the issue that the response of the AJAX call is dependant on the outcome of a CRON action, which is scheduled for some future unspecified date? Also note that `async: false` is horrendous practice and should be removed ASAP.

Comment: oh `async:false`, i didnt notice that @RoryMcCrossan. i wonder why anyone would do that :S

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ->  hi ajax call response is dependent on the out come of the cron job output

Comment: In that case you cannot return data in a single AJAX call as the CRON outcome is not immediately returned. You will need another method to notify the user when the CRON job completes.